wkhtmltopdf error when using as composer require instead binary
I'm trying to use the laravel-snappy package without installing the wkhtmltopdf on my own machine, so I'm using the "wkhtmltopdf binary as composer dependencies" section on this article. But when I try to run the wkhtmltopdf itself, I get these errors:
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks                  ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_peer_certificate
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
Error: Failed loading page  (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownNetworkError
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callbackhttps://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy#wkhtmltopdf-binary-as-composer-dependencies

Someone can help me?
I have tried install the openssl lib, the commons libs and things like this, but since I'm not using the binary on my own pc, I think that will not help.

Looking at the issues for h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64, the project has been abandoned, so it's stuck on wkhtmlto 0.12.4 instead of 0.12.6. You may need to install the binary on your system instead, or you can look through the issues/forks of either repository to find an alternative.

Oh, thanks for the info! Will use the binary on my system so, thank u again.
